# Function blocks and subsystems open in a new window

Tags: matlab, simulink

I use Simulink with many Subsystems. If I open a Block, a new window will appear. 
That's quit annoying, if you open 10 blocks.

I know there must be a possibility to change that behavior. So that the new block is displayed in the existing window.

But how can I configure that?

Comment: There is an interesting feature of this "annoying" behaviour. Simulinks remembers shape and locations of the block windows in a model. So if you take care of correctly resizing and locating each window once, later they will maintain the form. Then it is only how tidy you are...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simulink window/model behaviour changed considerably in R2012b.

Prior to 2012b there is a preference to control how/whether a new window opens when you double-click on a subsystem.
See http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2009/11/18/back-seat-driver-simulink-tips-for-efficient-model-navigation/ for info on setting the preference.

For 2012b, when tabbed windows were introduced, the preference disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

As found [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/simulink/ug/using-the-model-editor.html#btiiwpd):

> You can use tabs in the Simulink Editor to make it easier to navigate
>   between model windows for the top model and subsystems. To open a
>   subsystem in a separate tab:
>
> - Right-click the Subsystem block.
> - From the context-menu, select Open In
>     New Tab.

I am not aware of any short(er) cuts for this action, or that is is possible to set this as the default; I would just *love* it if this were possible...

Comment: I just can select "Open" or "Open in a new Window" but both have the same effect -> new window

Comment: The tabbed window feature appeared from R2012b.

Comment: @Peter: What version of MATLAB do you have?